# Strange boost::this_thread::sleep behavior

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I was trying to implement small time delays in multithreading code using boost::this_thread::sleep. 
Here is code example:

```
{
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;//just to check sleep interval
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(25));
}
```

Output generated by auto_cpu_timer confused me little bit:

```
0.025242s wall, 0.010000s user + 0.020000s system = 0.030000s CPU (118.9%)
```

Why it **0.025242s** but not 0.0025242s ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 25 milliseconds is 0.025 seconds; 0.0025 seconds would be 2.5 milliseconds.